# Qt QML for Android bugs

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

**Guys I'm writing an Instant Messaging app with Qt 5.14, and I am trying to deploy it for Android devices**

I've installed these:

- OpenJDK 8 (amd64)
- NDK r20b
- Qt Creator 4.11.0
- Qt 5.14 (for Android ARM64-v8a device)

I can build the app correctly, but when I run it from the phone, there's only a white screen

From Qt Creator I can see this application output

```
I nixsoftware.as: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I Perf    : Connecting to perf service.
E nixsoftware.as: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
E Qt      : Can't create main activity
E Qt      : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0
E Qt      :     at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:597)
E Qt      :     at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getStringArray(MiuiResources.java:160)
E Qt      :     at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp(QtLoader.java:423)
E Qt      :     at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate(QtActivityLoader.java:183)
E Qt      :     at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreateHook(QtActivity.java:266)
E Qt      :     at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:273)
E Qt      :     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
E Qt      :     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
E Qt      :     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
E Qt      :     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
E Qt      :     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
E Qt      :     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
E Qt      :     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E Qt      :     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E Qt      :     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
E Qt      :     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E Qt      :     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
E Qt      :     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
E Qt      :     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E Qt      :     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
E Qt      :     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : cf57c9c, I1cb5c4d1cc
I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 09/23/18
I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
I Adreno  : Local Branch                     :
I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    :
I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    :
I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               :
I Adreno  : Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch32
I Adreno  : PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
```

**Please help**

I can give you more info

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the similar behaviour after upgrading to Qt 5.14. Searching the Qt bugreports lead me to [QTBUG-80266](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80266). As suggested in comments, I re-created the AndroidManifest.xml and added back my local changes, my app now executes.
I hope it helps.